# Sequelize create and populate foreignKey

Tags: mysql, promise, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

Writing a recipe app, and using Sequelize with MySQL.

There are two relevant tables: **Recipes** table, and **RecipeAmounts** table with a foreignKey of **RecipeId**.

A recipe can have one or more ingredients based on the user input. When adding a recipe, both **Recipes** and **RecipeAmounts** tables have to be populated.

I've created the function below with promises, but I don't understand how I can correctly populate the **RecipeId** foreignKey in the RecipeAmounts. It has to be the same as **id** of the newly added recipe in the **Recipes** table.

```
exports.addRecipe = function (req, res) {

  var promises = [];

  promises.push(
    db.Recipe.create({
      RecipeName: req.body.RecipeName,
      RecipeDescription: req.body.RecipeDescription
    })
  )

  for (var i = 0; i < req.body.RecipeIngredients.length; i++) {
    promises.push(
      db.RecipeAmount.create({
        Amount: req.body.RecipeIngredients[i].AmountForSmall,
        Size: 'sm',
        Type: 'smoothie',
        // IngredientId: 10,
        // RecipeId: 1
      })
    );

    promises.push(
      db.RecipeAmount.create({
        Amount: req.body.RecipeIngredients[i].AmountForMedium,
        Size: 'md',
        Type: 'smoothie',
        // IngredientId: 10,
        // RecipeId: 1
      })
    );

    promises.push(
      db.RecipeAmount.create({
        Amount: req.body.RecipeIngredients[i].AmountForLarge,
        Size: 'lg',
        Type: 'smoothie',
        // IngredientId: 10,
        // RecipeId: 1
      })
    );
  }
  sequelize.Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
    console.log("all the files were created");
});

};
```

I've tried just to hard-code the **RecipeId** for testing purposes, but when I do that I get this error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Got it working with this:**

```
exports.addRecipe = function (req, res) {
    db.Recipe.create({
      RecipeName: req.body.RecipeName,
      RecipeDescription: req.body.RecipeDescription
    }).then(function(newRecipe) {
        var promises = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < req.body.RecipeIngredients.length; i++) {
            var RecipeId = newRecipe.dataValues.id;
            console.log(newRecipe.dataValues.id);
            promises.push(
              db.RecipeAmount.create({
                Amount: req.body.RecipeIngredients[i].AmountForSmall,
                Size: 'sm',
                Type: 'smoothie',
                // IngredientId: 10,
                RecipeId: RecipeId
              })
            );

            promises.push(
              db.RecipeAmount.create({
                Amount: req.body.RecipeIngredients[i].AmountForMedium,
                Size: 'md',
                Type: 'smoothie',
                // IngredientId: 10,
                RecipeId: RecipeId
              })
            );

            promises.push(
              db.RecipeAmount.create({
                Amount: req.body.RecipeIngredients[i].AmountForLarge,
                Size: 'lg',
                Type: 'smoothie',
                // IngredientId: 10,
                RecipeId: RecipeId
              })
            );
          }

          sequelize.Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
            console.log('All done YAYYYYYYY!!!!!!!');
          });
```